# Are all weight 5/2 modular forms theta series?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, theta-series

Given a quadratic form in $5$ variables, the theta series is a weight $5/2$ modular form. For a weight $3/2$ modular form we know that there always is a linear combination of theta series that work via the solution to the basis problem. But I have not found a reference addressing this in the $5/2$ case: it seems that Pizer adds weight instead of dimensions in his work to get higher weight classical forms.

Comment: You are asking about the Shimura decomposition of half-integral weight cusp forms $\mathcal{S}_{k/2}(q,\chi)$. It is well-known that for $k \geq 5$ odd, $\mathcal{S}_{k/2}(q,\chi)$ is usually not only spanned by theta series (the exceptions occur only for $q$ small). See http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/mf.half_integral_weight.shimura_decomposition

Comment: The notation in the LMFDB link is meant to indicate that $S_{0}(N,\chi)$ is the space spanned by so-called "unary theta series" (expression of the form $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \chi(n) n q^{n^{2}}$, where $\chi$ is an odd Dirichlet character). For this reason, I do not see the relation to the OP's question.

Comment: Naive comment. Weight 1 modular forms can be arithmetically very subtle (e.g. they can correspond to Galois representations cutting out non-solvable extensions of the rationals). If I take such a thing and multiply it by the standard weight $1/2$ theta series, surely I get a weight $3/2$ form that cannot possibly be a linear combination of theta series? Certainly in weight 1 the subspace of forms generated by theta series is just the space spanned by the eigenforms giving rise to dihedral Galois reps. So I'm a bit confused. Maybe my definition of weight $3/2$ form is wrong?

Comment: @znt Multiplying modular forms is a rather brutal operation, and one that really has no analogue whatsoever on the "Galois side". So I think your intuition that "surely" the product can't be a linear combination of theta series is not going to work. For comparison, Borisov--Gunnells have shown that the ring of modular forms generated by weight 1 Eisenstein series contains *all* cusp forms of integral weights $\ge 3$.

Comment: @David Loeffler: the dihedral subspace of the weight 1 forms is precisely that spanned by the product of weight 1/2 forms. The quadratic forms in 1 variable become quadratic forms in 2 variables. I agree that products of Eisenstein series can't be controlled (see e.g. level 1) but theta series are different.